# Why does Service destroy self when Activity is destroyed?

Tags: android, service, binding, destroy

I want to start a service from an Activity then have it keep running even when the activity exits / finishes.  Then when i launch the app activity again it reattaches to the existing service.

I've read the docs on bindService but each time i hit the back button to exit the activity the onUnBind of the Service is being automatically called effectively killing the service.  I thought i must call unbindService manually before the service is unbound.

I do undertsnad that once the Activity is destroyed the member variables mService, mBound, and tv have to be repopulated once the new Activity is created and so it isnt a surprise the simple code below will show *"bindService started."* but I would have thought all the member variables within the LocalService instance would be the same, unchanged and so the *"bindService already Started. Val = " + mService.myval;*  should remain the same each time i relaunch a new Activity, should it not?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    LocalService mService;
    Boolean mBound = false;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onButtonStart(View v)
    {
        String str;

        // Bind to LocalService
        if (!mBound)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);

            if (!bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE))
            {
                unbindService(mConnection);
                str = "bindService failed?!";
            }
            else
            {
                str = "bindService started.";
            }
        }
        else
            str = "bindService already Started. Val = " + mService.myval;

        tv.setText(str);
    }  

    public void onButtonStop(View v)
    {
        if (mBound)
        {
            mService.stop();
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;

            tv.setText("Stopped Service");
        }
        else
            tv.setText("Service is not running");
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection()
    {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service)
        {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            LocalService.LocalBinder binder = (LocalService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0)
        {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };   
 }
```

**LocalService**

```
public class LocalService extends Service
{
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();
    public int myval = getRandomNumber();

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    // Service is being Destroyed
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public int getRandomNumber()
    {
        return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return mBinder;
    }

    // Client is Unbinding via the unbindService() call
    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
    {
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder
    {
        public LocalService getService()
        {
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are using `bindService()`.

> A bound service typically lives only while it serves another application component and does not run in the background indefinitely.

So if your Activity (which bound to service) is finised then Service will no longer running .

To run a service in back ground you have to create a `STICKY` service with flag `START_STICKY`.

```
 @Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  // Do your task here
  return START_STICKY;
 }
```

An `START_STICKY` service can run in background without any activity presence . And you can communicate with service with callbacks.

For creating a `Sticky service` read [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) .

Comment: I noticed that with this, service destroyed when we kill the app and it calls onCreate and onStartCommand methods again...

Comment: Not in case of `bindService()` . This will be the case of `startService()` . A service can be binded or started both.